# Why does Jenkins change my gradlew, and how to prevent that?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, gradlew, gradle-release-plugin

I'm trying to 'release' my project using the [gradle release-plugin](https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-release)

The plugin starts by checking if my working copy is clean, so that only properly versioned stuff gets released.

This works just fine on my local machine. But when I try the same thing in a Jenkins job, the build fails complaining various stuff is changed in the workplace. I decided that a lot of stuff was just internally used by jenkins and added it to `gitignore`:

```
caches/
native/
wrapper/
```

But it also considers `gradlew` as changed:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':checkCommitNeeded'.
> You have uncommitted files:
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   M gradlew
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Why does Jenkins change that file how do I prevent that?**

I think the following settings on the Jenkins job might be relevant:

- `Checkout/merge to local branch (optional)` is set to master. Without this setting the release plugin complains about not being on a branch
- `Clean after checkout` is currently checked, but checking/unchecking it didn't make a difference
- `Make gradlew executable` is checked, and at least to me sounds like a likely cause, but unchecking it makes the build faile because gradlew is not executable

Comment: I don't think gradlew will be changed unless you run a gradle task of type Wrapper.

Comment: I kind of agree. But I don't know what is causing wrapper to run. It certainly isn't among the tasks I explicitly call, nor do they have wrapper as a dependency (at least that would be a mighty strange dependency)

Comment: I have created a bug for this with the jenkins gradle plugin: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17505

Answer (score 9):

Pretty old question, but for the record to anyone coming over here, jenkins isn't at fault here, you should commit gradlew with executable bit set:

```
# git update-index --chmod=+x gradlew
# git commit
```

Then you will no longer need the jenkins setting to set it executable, which is the workaround causing your issue.